# Desktop AIR application using PHP?

Tags: php, air, wamp, desktop-application, easyphp

I wonder what is the best approach ( and is it even possible ), to execute some PHP functions and get returned data from them in my Adobe AIR desktop app.

PS. My PHP code is hosted locally via Easy PHP ( WAMP ) server.

Answer (score 0):

You can code air using javascript / jquery. The best approach is to make ajax requests to your php files, but it has to be hosted on a publicly accessible domain

Comment: google is your friend. try searching for "jquery ajax request from air" or similar